# Installing PIL on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hey, i have a problem installing PIL on Snow.

I have a clean installation of macports after the upgrade to SL and installed from source the jpeg library following the OS specific installation instructions. Installing PIL with pip goes well but when i try to import the _imaging module i get the following message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture`

Answer (score 3):

MacPorts already has a PIL port that will do all the work for you!

```
sudo port install py26-pil
```

You should first go into the site-packages directory and elsewhere to remove the stuff you installed manually, though.  MacPorts will install all the necessary dependent libraries.

Comment: I found you need to make sure these files in particular
(pilconvert.py,
pildriver.py,
pilconvert.py,
pilprint.py,
pilfont.py )
 need to be deleted from /site-packages if they already exist there when installing py26-pil from Macports... The install balked until these were cleared out.

Comment: This solution is trying to install all possible things it seems and it is going forever on my machine. Anything I am missing? Honestly, I only need to install PIL. But this is installing python 2.6.6, python 2.7, openssl etc when I run the command.

Comment: The above command should not be trying to install python2.7, only python2.6.  You can see what dependent packages MacPorts will try to install by doing a test run: `sudo port -y install py26-pil`.  And, yes, if you know what you are doing or are willing to spend the time to figure out what all the necessary configuration options are, you can try to just install `pil` and its immediate dependencies, `libjpeg`, `freetype`, etc, but you need to know what ABI (`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`) and CPU archs the Python you are using was configured and built with. Using MacPorts eliminates the guess work.

Comment: @Maccesch: it depends what you are trying to do.  If you are using Python 2.7, yes, but Mac OS X Lion also ships with Python 2.6 and even Python 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

PIL on Mac OS X has been a pain point for many of my friends. These instructions seem to often help speedup the enlightenment process:

http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/installing-pil-on-mac-os-x-leopard/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, and actually created a small tutorial on how to resolve this.
getting a working copy of PIL, libjpeg and Imaging on Snow Leopard or even Lion

My default version of Python was still on 2.6 so I had to switch to 2.7

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.7
```

get v8c of jpeg
cd into jpeg directory.

```
sudo make clean
CC="gcc -arch i386" ./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
```

get imaging i am using 1.1.6

untar
cd into imaging

```
sudo rm -rf build
vi setup.py
JPEG_ROOT = libinclude(“/usr/local/lib”)
sudo python setup.py install
```

And it’s that simple

Run your python interpreter,

```
import PIL
import _imaging
import Image
```

if all is well, then your all set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain (I use a PC myself), but I think that you might find something interesting [here](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/fall/python.shtml)

May the force be with you